# How do I handle "connection failed due to invalid command line" error?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I've installed all the necessary components: *sdk, toolkit, Windows7 SP1, Visual Studio 2010 SP1*, but it's not working. It is giving me an invalid command line argument error on running.

Comment: usually is a faulty installation. try to unistall wp7 dev tools, delete "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Phone Tools" content and try again. Other reason could be the lack of free RAM memory in your dev PC. let us know...

Answer (score 1):

Please install Media Format Feature Pack for Windows and retry. It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too, if you have an N or NK version of windows7 without a Windows Media Player I was getting the same issue. Installing media player fixed the issue... odd but it gets it going